# Are there any online platforms where I can discuss my research idea with experts?

Tags: independent-researcher, biology

I have several research ideas (oncology and virology) that I want to discuss with professors/experts, so I am looking for an online platform where the ideas can be shared and discussed. However, other than Researchgate (which I cannot use, because I don't have an institutional email), I can't seem to find any other suitable places on the web. Biology Stack Exchange didn't work well for me, because the mods there say that my question is mainly based on "opinion."

So......in short,any good forums or platforms where I can discuss my ideas with the experts?

Comment: I flagged this as being a shopping question, but besides that I'm not sure the question is answerable without knowing why you want to discuss them. Are they ideas you think people ought to be pursuing? Are they ideas for future research that you'd like to pursue? Do you just want feedback on whether they're interesting?

Comment: _Researchgate (which I cannot use, because I don't have an institutional email),_ I am an independent researcher and I do have an account. I don't know what you're talking about. Short answer to your question: Go to school to receive formal training in Biology. Biology is not something you can study at home. You need to work in labs. Of course, you can build your own lab if you are a billionare.

Comment: since you are an independent researcher, this question is a bit out of place here in academia. You might want to try one of the [Area51 proposals](http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/7/science)

Comment: @brucellino not at all - questions about research outside of academia are also on topic here. We have an existing tag, [tag:independent-researcher] for questions about researchers with no affiliation. We also accept questions from researchers in [tag:industry] or [tag:government-institutes]

Comment: Thanks for setting me straight! I actually came to that realisation reading about the open science proposed site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Quora](https://www.quora.com/) to ask your questions and also discuss with experts on your interested field.

This site needs registration with your email (institution based is not required).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Guaana](https://www.guaana.com/) to engage experts

Another good idea would be to use [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com), where depending on your research field you may or may not find an engaged scientific community. However, research is not simply "ask question, get answer". You need to understand the field and depending on the research field, you may find that it is near impossible to even communicate with researchers in a field, if you yourself are not part of it. If you're really serious about your ideas, I would look  for a biotech consultancy and hire them to develop the ideas.